# Extracting common functionality in Django management commands

Tags: python, django

What is the generally accepted way for isolating functionality that is shared between multiple management commands in a given app?  For example, I have some payload building code that is used across multiple management commands that access a third-party API.  Is the proper location `app_name/manangement/helpers.py` which would then be imported in a management command with `from ..helpers import build_api_payload`?

I don't want to put it at the root of the app (we typically use `app_name/helpers.py` for shared functionality), since it pulls in dev dependencies that wouldn't exist in production, and is never really used outside the management command anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with `app_name/manangement/helpers.py`.  No issues.